# "Imprecise faults" and SIMD

Tags: c#, cil

I'm looking through the [CIL Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf).  In an appendix, it talks about "Imprecise faults", meaning that a user could specify that the exact order of null reference exceptions, etc. could be relaxed.  The appendix talks about various ways in which this could be used by the JITer to improve performance.

One specific subsection that caught my eye:

> **F.5.2 Vectorizing a loop**
>
> Vectorizing a loop usually requires knowing
>   two things:
>
> 1. The loop iterations are independent
> 2. The number of loop iterations is known.
>
> In a method relaxed for the checks that might fault, part 1 is
>   frequently false, because the possibility of a fault induces a control
>   dependence from each loop iteration to succeeding loop iterations.  In
>   a relaxed method, those control dependences can be ignored. In most
>   cases, relaxed methods simplify vectorization by allowing checks to be
>   hoisted out of a loop.  Nevertheless, even when such hoisting is not
>   possible, ignoring cross-iteration  dependences implied by faults can
>   be crucial to vectorization for “short vector” SIMD hardware such as
>   IA-32 SSE or PowerPC Altivec.
>
> For example, consider this loop:
>
> ```
> for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
>    x[k] = x[k] + y[k] * s[k].a;
> }
> ```
>
> where s is an array of references.  The checks for null references
>   cannot be hoisted out of the loop, even in a relaxed context.   But
>   relaxed does allow “unroll-and-jam” to be applied successfully.  The
>   loop can be unrolled by a factor of 4 to create aggregate iterations,
>   and the checks hoisted to the top of each aggregate iteration.

That is, it's suggesting that the loop could be automatically turned to SIMD operations by the JITer if it were using these relaxed faults.  The spec suggests that you can set these relaxed faults by using the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxations enum.  But in actual C# the enum only has the NoStringInterning option without any of the others.  I've tried hard setting the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute to some int codes pulled from [other sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/pnetlib-doc/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/CompilationRelaxations.html), but there was no difference in the x86 assembly produced.

So as far as I can tell the official Microsoft JIT does not implement this.  And I know Mono has the [Mono.Simd](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3aMono.Simd) namespace, so my guess is it doesn't implement this, either.

So I'm curious if there's some piece of history about that appendix (and section 12.6.4 "Optimization", which talks about this, too) that I'm missing.  Why is it in the standard if neither major vendor actually implements it?  Are there plans from Microsoft to work on it in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> So I'm curious if there's some piece of history about that appendix (and section 12.6.4 "Optimization", which talks about this, too) that I'm missing. Why is it in the standard if neither major vendor actually implements it? Are there plans from Microsoft to work on it in the future?

I suspect this was put in the specifically to provide the option to allow this to be implemented at some point without breaking the implementation or requiring a specification change.

> But in actual C# the enum only has the NoStringInterning option without any of the others

This is because the `NoStringInterning` is the only supported option at this time.  As enum in C# is extensible (its just an underlying integer type), a future version of the runtime could easily be extended to support other options.

Note that there are [suggestions on the VS UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2212443-c-and-simd) site for Microsoft to make improvements in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Such are the burdens of the guy that has to write the CLI spec, he doesn't yet know if actually implementing this in a jitter is practical.  That happens later.

SIMD is a problem, it has a pretty hard variable alignment requirement.  At least around the time that the x86 jitter was written, trying to apply a SIMD instruction on a mis-aligned variable produced a hard bus fault.  Not so sure what state of the art was when the x64 jitter was written but today it is still very expensive.  The x86 jitter can't do better than 4 byte alignment, x64 can't do better than 8.  It might require the next generation 128-bit core to get the 16-byte alignment to really make it effective.  I'm not holding my breath for that :)

Comment: Yeah, the alignment requirement is a pain.  But SIMD would mostly make sense with for loops over arrays anyway.  I wouldn't expect it to be that big a pain to 16 byte align arrays specifically.  That wouldn't handle all cases, of course, but I think it'd make sense for the most common case.

But I'm not a JIT designer.  Reading the CIL spec, the JITer has to worry about some really gnarly edge cases that almost never matter except when they do :)

Comment: Arrays are managed objects in a managed language.  So yes, that alignment requirement is a pain.  The current GC heap implementation cannot provide better alignment than the native pointer size by design.  Changing that is either very painful or very wasteful.

Comment: The main wasteful aspect would be if the allocation size is below some threshold, right?  So I don't feel like it'd be hard to add in an alignment requirement (by inflating the allocation size request, or other means) to large allocations only. 

It's easy enough to check for alignment after the fact (is the low 4 bits of the pointer address 0?) and you could turn on/off SIMD optimizations based on that, if you had to.

The main problem would be if meta information is stored in the top bytes of an allocation, or something like that.

Comment: No, the garbage collector moves objects around when it compacts the heap.  Whatever alignment it had before is not the alignment it has afterwards.  Dealing with that is the painful part.  Unless the heap implementation *always* ensures 16 byte alignment.  That's the wasteful part.

Comment: Yes, but it still has to allocate the place it's going to move the object to, and so can align the new allocation just as easily as it had the old one.

Comment: Now you're advocating the *painful* part instead of the sloppy part, making the collector somehow aware of the objects if moves around.

Comment: Er, I might be misunderstanding something.  The garbage collector is _already_ aware of the objects it moves around, right?  It knows the size of the allocation, and it wouldn't be hard for it to know that it's above a certain size, and so to align it.  Alternatively, you could just make the allocator always make aligned allocations, and make it something that can be toggled on the assembly level similar to CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning.  Plus, most small allocations are value types, and are usually on the stack instead of the heap (unless they're boxed, which is rare).

Comment: No, the collector only knows that an object of a class derived from System.Object is getting moved around.  It neither knows nor cares about the specific type of object.  Also, the actual size of the heap block doesn't match the object size for small objects.  Which there are plenty of due to boxing or simple classes with one or two fields.  What you propose isn't impossible, it is just a high cost for a minor feature.  Executing SIMD code in a managed program is supported anyway, write the code in C++/CLI.  No different from the way it is done in C++.

Comment: That's about it for me btw.  Consider posting a feature request at connect.microsoft.com, the only guys that can actually make this happen.  And you can of course tinker without constraint with Mono.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old thread, but @HansPassant you say x86 can only align 4 and x64 can only 8, why is that? what requirement forces them to align max to that? And why not 16? Is it just size overhead?